# Send image and videos files from android to a server and receive processed

Tags: java, android, sockets, image-processing

I want to send video/images from the android mobile to a server and recieve the video/image processed. (For example, I send an image and recieve this image as binary image or gray scale or resized, etc)
What's the best and easiest way to do it guys? Http? Sockets? XML? And how to do it?

I was trying to do it by stream ([Shared Library not found error on android LogCat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11248509/shared-library-not-found-error-on-android-logcat)) but I couldn't manage how to do it as well.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, here are some general advices before answering specific parts of your question:

**Try to do the trivial things on the device.** Just putting a mask on an image or rotating/resizing it is very trivial and can be performed on the device. This way, the user does not need to upload anything (and *wait*) and your server isn't as heavily loaded.

**Videos and pictures can grow big.** Take this into account. An idea that comes to mind is, that a user should upload the image/video just once, but should be able to perform multiple manipulations before downloading the *final* result. Otherwise, you'll end up with long waiting-times and high traffic.

**Tell your users!** If you really start uploading (maybe personal) pictures/videos to your own Server, ensure that you're using the maximal security you can get (SSL should be a must-have) and tell your users that you'll upload their content to your server. Also, you should give them the option to decline on that, otherwise, you might face a lawsuit.

---

Now, to the technical part of it:

The workflow for up-/downloading files to/from a server is almost always the same:

- Open a connection to your server, using a [`Socket`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html)
- Get a Stream on your file (in your case, a [`FileInputStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/FileInputStream.html))
- Read chunks of binary data in a `byte`-array
- Write the read chunks to the output stream from the Socket
- When you're done, close the streams and then the socket

On your server, you do it the other way around and read from the InputStream, writing the content to a [`FileOutputStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/FileOutputStream.html).

Here is a small example of how this can look:

```
Socket server = new Socket("192.168.178.32", 1337);
OutputStream outputStream = server.getOutputStream();
FileInputStream in = null;
try {
    in = new FileInputStream("/some/path/to/gras.jpeg");
    // Write to the stream:
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024]; // 1KB buffer size
    int length = 0;
    while ( (length = in.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length)) != -1 ){
        outputStream.write(buffer, 0, length);
    }
    outputStream.flush();
} finally {
    if (in != null) in.close();
    socket.close(); // Will close the outputStream, too.
}
```

This code dismisses the fact that there are exception which might be thrown here. You'll need to handle those in an appropriated way.

---

Something which you should take into account is, that users might upload their content from a **mobile internet connection**, which can be intercepted (for example when going through a tunnel). In this case, you'll want to implement the up/download to be resumable.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Your example, the client send an image, how could it recieve the processed image? Do I have to open a server to listen a conexion after send the image?

Comment: Since it can take some time to process a big video file (for example), you might want to use some Cloud2Device communication for push-notifications on when the processing has been done. Have a look at [Google GCM](http://developer.android.com/guide/google/gcm/index.html) for example.